# How to solve this error with matlabprefs.mat

Tags: matlab

Executing a small piece of code (MWE not relevant), I obtained following error message:

```
Error using load
Unable to read MAT-file /Users/.../.matlab/R2012b/matlabprefs.mat: not a
binary MAT-file.
Try LOAD -ASCII to read as text.
Error in prefutils>loadPrefs (line 43)
fileContents = load(prefFile);

Error in prefutils (line 11)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(varargin{:});

Error in ispref (line 32)
Preferences = prefutils('loadPrefs');

Error in mpt_subSolvers (line 11)
if ispref('MPT','MPTOPTIONS')

Error in mptopt (line 156)
    function options = mptopt(varargin)

Error in Polyhedron (line 422)
            MPTOPTIONS = mptopt;
```

Somebody suggested to delete the file `matlabprefs.mat` ([Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpt-user/9iMfrn4S4yQ)) but I cannot locate this file. Is there any hint about how to preceed to solve this problem?

Comment: `matlabprefs.mat` should be in your local user configuration directory. In Unix that's normally `~/.matlab/Rxyz/`. Another thing you can try is to change the preferences from within Matlab (), hoping that the file gets overwritten.

Comment: you got a hint in the error message: "_/Users/.../.matlab/R2012b/matlabprefs.mat_". Part is missing but that should guide you. Just remember that folder names starting with a dot `.` are hidden, so they may not show depending on your settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was indeed to delete the file `matlabprefs.mat`(that was empty). In order to do so, I had to make hidden files visible. More information on doing this on Mac can be found [here](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/).